# JAXB unmarshal instances of subclasses into List

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

say i want to represent arithmetic expressions using xml, so i have:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlTransient
@XmlSeeAlso({Num.class, Add.class})
public abstract class Evaluable
{
    public abstract int eval();
}

@XmlRootElement
@XmlType(name = "num")
public class Num extends Evaluable
{
    @XmlValue
    private int val;

    @Override
    public int eval()
    {
        return val;
    }
}

@XmlRootElement
@XmlType
public class Add extends Evaluable
{
    @XmlAnyElement
    private ArrayList<Evaluable> elems;

    @Override
    public int eval()
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for (Evaluable elem : elems)
        {
            sum += elem.eval();
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

and my test case:

```
public class RecursiveUnmarshalTest
{
    @Test
    public void testAdd() throws Exception
    {
        String xml = "<add><num>10</num><num>20</num></add>";
        assertEquals(30,
                ((Evaluable) JAXBContext.newInstance(Evaluable.class).createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(new StringReader(
                        xml))).eval());

    }
}
```

the problem here is that non-`Evaluable` is stored in the `ArrayList` in `Add` and the reason is due to type erasure, JAXB doesn't know which type the elements should reflect to, so there will be a cast error in the eval of `Add`.

and i tested that by doing:

```
public class Add extends Evaluable
{
    @XmlElements({
            @XmlElement(name = "num", type = Num.class),
            @XmlElement(name = "add", type = Add.class)
    })
    private ArrayList<Evaluable> elems;
...
```

this will be fixed.

but i don't want to spread this table all over the world. if i want to append some subtypes, things are going to be messy.

so my question is which annotation is suitable for my case? or any system to type to unmarshaller?

i am using glassfish's JAXB and i couldn't choose implementation to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `@XmlElementRef` to get the behaviour you are looking for:

```
@XmlElementRef
private ArrayList<Evaluable> elems;
```

---

### UPDATE

> it says Evaluable or any of its subclasses are not known to this
>   context

Ahh, that's right because you have Marked `Evaluable` as `@XmlTransient`, JAXB ignores it and doesn't consider that it exists.  You probably added it because when you don't have it you get the following exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
Invalid @XmlElementRef : Type "class forum27826242.Evaluable" or any of its subclasses are not known to this context.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at private java.util.ArrayList forum27826242.Add.elems
        at forum27826242.Add
        at @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSeeAlso(value=[class forum27826242.Num, class forum27826242.Add])
        at forum27826242.Num
```

Comment: it says `Evaluable or any of its subclasses are not known to this context`.

Comment: i add it because i want `text` in `num`. i searched around, in my particular implementation of JAXB, to allow this, having `XmlTransient` is the only way, isn't it?